# I want to start and stop localhost server (Remote machine) using Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

There is a one service which is running on localhost (remote machine) and needs to be START before running
the HTTP sampler and STOP after execution. Ex- http://localhost:8080//XYZ. Is it possible to send instruction to that remote machine from jmeter to start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

It is, depending on the operating system of the remote machine and the machine where JMeter is running you can use:

1. [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)
2. [SSH Command Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command)
3. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [JCIFS](https://www.jcifs.org/) library

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) for more information on the overall concept and some examples.